# How does this fire alarm system transmit data on two-wire?

Tags: communication, transmitter, protocol

In the fire detection industry, analogue addressable systems use control panels and detectors (and devices such as interfaces) which communicate with each other by means of a protocol.

What protocol is this?

[image: Analogue addressable system diagram]

Can anyone help me find information about it?

Comment: Honeywell defined such a protocol, decades ago. About 20 volt signaling, on an 80 volt DC power rail. All this from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What protocol is used is impossible to say unless I have access to the technical documentation of the units and/or can reverse-engineer them.

We can assume that it is some kind of communication protocol suitable for one shared connection (no separate TX, RX, clock etc. but one bidirectional signal).

With some electronics it is possible to make data and power share the same pair of wires. This is nothing new, the old wired telephone system already used it!

Here are some links that show how this can be done:

[Transmit Digital Signals and Power Over Same Wires](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1863)

[Using SN65HVD96 to Create a Power-Over-Data and Polarity Immunity Solution](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla336/slla336.pdf)

The basic idea is that the power is DC and the data is AC. With some electronics (that can be as simple as an RC filter or a transformer) the two (data, power) can be combined and separated in each device.

Comment: Thanks for your share. It's a useful information for me

Answer (score 0):

If you visit [bacnet.org](http://www.bacnet.org/), you will find all the major fire alarm manufacturers are listed as members. The protocol was started in the mid 80s and has evolved. It's called [BACnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BACnet).

When I youtube it, it wants to point me to rs485, yet I know 485 maxes out at 64 devices? Uses terminating resistors, uses 2 conductors plus plus and minus.

Comment: Hi Carl and welcome. Whilst this appears to answer the question, there is also another question contained within it. Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not your usual forum of threaded messages. Please separate, and edit out the question and [ask] your own question, referring back to thsi question, using the URL, if need be. To learn more about how SE works, please take the [tour].

Comment: RS-485 doesn't max out at 64 devices if you use the right transceivers. It's all about max capacitive loading presented by the receivers. You should delete this post and post it as a brand new question.

Comment: Any rs485 I have worked with max out around 64, and always wants a terminating resistor 470 ohms I remember, just to keep the noise down.

Answer (score 0):

The fire sensor might use M-Bus or a protocol (most likely, proprietary) similar to M-Bus.

[image]

To transmit the command, the master sends it as a voltage impulses. To transmit the answer, the peripheral uses short high current consumption impulses.

Answer (score -1):

I studied the technologies about how to transmit data and power on two-wire and found an answer for this issue.

The result of study show that analog 4–20 mA current loops are commonly used for electronic signalling, with the two values of 4 & 20 mA representing 0–100% of the range of measurement or control. These loops are used both for carrying sensor information from field instrumentation, and carrying control signals to the process modulating devices, such as a valve
In the case of a fire alarm, 6 mA could be normal, 15 mA could mean a fire has been detected, and 0 mA would produce a trouble indication, telling the monitoring site the alarm circuit had failed.

Some 4–20 mA field devices can be powered by the current loop itself, removing the need for separate power supplies, and the "smart" HART protocol uses the loop for communications between field devices and controllers. Here are some links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop

https://fieldcommgroup.org/technologies/hart/hart-technology-detail

However, I haven't make sure that the addressable fire alarm Systems are using.
Can anyone help me confirm that this is right or wrong?